# Touch Bar randomly clicks buttons by itself

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

I have noticed three separate recurring behaviors:

1. While typing in Safari, it would automatically switch to the first tab.
2. In other applications, the emoji picker would open randomly.
3. While in any application, my computer would randomly go to sleep.
4. While in Safari, I would randomly get switched to the lab tab.

Weird.

There's only one explanation that makes sense:

It’s the Touch Bar.

1. The Touch Bar has a button for switching to the first tab in Safari (on the extreme left side).
2. It also has a button for the emoji picker (also on the extreme left).
3. The way I’ve customized my Touch Bar, there is also a Touch Bar button for sending my computer to sleep (right-most button of control-strip).
4. Finally, the Touch Bar also as a button for switching to the last tab in Safari.

So . . . the Touch Bar must be registering false positive touches.

The only common thing about all these behaviors—switching tabs, the emoji picker, sleeping—is that they all have a Touch Bar button.

Could I be accidentally hitting the Touch Bar with my fingers while typing?

Possibly. I don’t think so, but it’s possible.

One additional detail: There are phases. Behavior (1) and (2) happened in the beginning, but it stopped (buttons on the left side). Now it’s behaviors (3) and (4) that are occurring (buttons on the right side).

How could I further diagnose this problem of false positive Touch Bar touches?

Comment: From time to time I encounter the same behaviour. This typically happens with me when I have many tabs open in several Safari windows (e.g., 60+ tabs in 4 windows). How many tabs/windows do you typically have opened when this happens?

Comment: @ShutterFreak Happens to me with as few as 2 tabs, as many as 15 tabs!

Comment: @ShutterFreak Update: Happens with other applications with other buttons in other places! Have you experienced this too? Does it seems to come and go in phases?

Comment: Happens to me also, even when i just scroll a page via the touchpad sometimes screen brightness is "clicked" by itself. So accidental typing is ruled out. I've noticed that this issue disappears when i disable the control strip (mini strip on right)... but thats a nasty workaround...